# How to perform intensive node.js computations

Tags: node.js, computation

I am working on an e-commerce app that has to re-calculate pricing for products every time products are sent from the server to the client (up to thousands of products are sent each time). The calculation piece itself is fairly intensive since it requires multiple database queries to calculate. My naive solution is to abstract the calculation part onto another node.js app/server that is solely dedicated to calculations. Does anyone know of a better or more scalable/optimal way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good first step abstracting the computations to other servers. I recommend looking into [AMQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) or Amazon's [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) and creating a distributed system if performance+reliability is such a concern. However, without knowing more specific info about the system, we can only give general advice.

Answer (score 2):

Defer the computation-heavy task to a dedicated node app is a good idea but beware that this app event loop will be blocked as well and won't be able to serve multiple request in parallel neither.

You will still have to spawn a dedicated process for the computation with either using [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) or `child_process.spawn()`).

There is a [fairly old but still good article](http://neilk.net/blog/2013/04/30/why-you-should-use-nodejs-for-CPU-bound-tasks/) about the different possible approaches.